# Как найти максимальные и минимальные значения в двумерном массиве?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Есть двумерный массив, к примеру такой:

```
const arr = [
    [1, 22, 43],
    [0, 26, 52],
    [5, 54, 12],
    [8, 76, 1],
    [9, 89, 5],
];
```

Но количество элементов не известно.
Необходимо найти максимальное и минимальное значение среди элементов массивов с одинаковым `id`, то есть взять все значения с `id = 0`, выбрать среди них максимум и минимум и так для всех `id`.
На выходе должен получится двумерный массив типа:

```
const arrMinMax = [
    [0, 9],
    [22, 89],
    [1, 52],
];
```

Я пытался сделать это с помощью циклов:

```
const newArr: number[][] = [];
    data.forEach((item, i) => {
        item.forEach((value, j) => {
            newArr[j].push(value as number);
        });
    });
```

Примерно так: выбрать все элементы с одинаковым `id` в один массив, а затем просто выбрать в каждом мин и макс, этого в коде нет, но проблема в том, что браузер выдает ошибку в этой части кода `newArr[j].push(value as number);`:

> Ошибка: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Я не могу присвоить значение несуществующему элементу массива.
Пишу на `typescript`, в обычном js такой ошибки вроде не будет. 
Или может быть у меня вообще подход не верный?

Comment: Какие у Вас с реализацией проблемы?

Comment: Если это вопрос, то логичным ответом будет : «Нет, такой поиск не является необходимым» :) А если это **не** вопрос - то напишите его... сформулировав так, чтобы он содержал и вашу попытку решения задачи, и возникшие при этом трудности.

Comment: А что именно не получается?

Comment: Я не вижу в вашем массиве что такое `id`. Столбец что ли?

Comment: Да, собрать весь столбец в один массив.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как Вы верно пишете в правке вопроса - причина ошибки в присвоении значения элементу *несуществующего* вложенного массива (вместо массива `undefined`, и при попытке вызова `undefined.push()` выбрасывается исключение).

Просто создавайте подмассив, если его еще нет:

```
const newArr: number[][] = [];
arr.forEach((item, i) => {
  item.forEach((value, j) => {
    if (!newArr[j])                   // <--
      newArr[j] = [];                 // <--
    newArr[j].push(value as number);
  });
});
```

[<kbd>Демо на JS Bin</kbd>](http://jsbin.com/qomabagobe/edit?js,console)

---

И, вот вариант полного решения задачи (без создания лишних промежуточных массивов):

```
const newArr: number[][] = [];
let row: number,                               // number number number 
    col: number,                               // number number number 
    val: number,                               // number number number 
    min: number,                               // num...   (╯°□°)╯︵ ┻━┻
    max: number;                               // что за недоязык?! 
for (col = 0; col < arr[0].length; col++) {
  min = +Infinity; 
  max = -Infinity; 
  for (row = 0; row < arr.length; row++) {
    val = arr[row][col]; 
    min = val < min ? val : min; 
    max = val > max ? val : max; 
  }
  newArr[col] = [min, max]; 
}
```

[<kbd>Демо на JS Bin</kbd>](http://jsbin.com/kejizenugi/edit?js,console)

Код относительно эффективен, но страшен... ибо он от яваскриптера, изучавшего TypeScript <10 минут. Надеюсь, кто-нибудь из знатоков TS напишет свой ответ с более красивым решением :)

Answer (score 0):

Решение в лоб

```js
const arr = [
    [1, 22, 43],
    [0, 26, 52],
    [5, 54, 12],
    [8, 76, 1],
    [9, 89, 5],
   [1, 9, 21]
];
const obj = {};
arr.forEach( item => {
 let [first, ...other] = item;
 if(!obj[first]){
  obj[first] = [...other]
  return;
 }
 obj[first].push(...other);
});
for(let id in obj){
 obj[id] = [Math.min(...obj[id]),Math.max(...obj[id])];
}
console.log(obj);
```